# how to distinguish expand vs click in fancytree?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, fancytree

```
>[\] Group
   >[\] Subgroup
      [] Item
      [] Item
      ...
   ...
...
```

I have tree like demonstrated. `[\]` implies that it is **not** selectable, while `[]` stands for checkbox, which can be selected.

I would like that **CLICKING** on Group or Subgroup implies:

- expand of all children below the clicked group/subgroup
- selection (or when it is second time unselection) of all items below

I would like that clicking on `>` implies only:

- expand of all children below the clicked group/subgroup

My code for now looks something like this:

```
createNode: (event, data) ->
    kind = data.node.data.k
    pk = data.node.data.i

    if objects?[pk]
        data.node.setSelected()

    if kind isnt 'c'
        $(data.node.li).find('span.fancytree-checkbox').remove()

beforeSelect: (event, data) ->
    if data.node.data.k isnt 'c'
        return false

    if data.node.isSelected() and data.node.parent.isSelected()
        return false
click: (event, data) ->
    data.node.visit (child) ->
        console.log data.node.data.k 
        child.makeVisible()
        if child.data.k is 'c'
            child.setSelected(data.node.selected)
```

and:

ajax:
        ifModified: true
        cache: true

```
checkbox: true
selectMode: 2
debugLevel: 0
generateIds: false

filter:
    mode: 'hide'
```

For now I have problem that clicking on '>' shows and hides the children below.

How to make properly the check:

```
event.originalEvent.target is 'fancytree-expander'
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
        tt = $.ui.fancytree.getEventTargetType(event.originalEvent)
        if tt isnt 'expander'
```